# Como pasar datos de blade a un archivo Js?

Tags: javascript, laravel

Tengo un archivo Js cuya función es crear un gráfico, pero me gustaría que los datos que use ese gráfico sean algunos que busco en unas consultas de eloquent que luego paso a mi vista en blade. Hay alguna forma de hacer esto?

Este es mi código en mi archivo Js, los valores que dicen data son los que vendrían de la vista:

```
var salesChart  = new Chart($salesChart, {
type   : 'bar',
data   : {
  labels  : ['JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: '#007bff',
      borderColor    : '#007bff',
      data           : [1000, 2000, 3000, 2500, 2700, 2500, 7000]
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: '#ced4da',
      borderColor    : '#ced4da',
      data           : [700, 1700, 2700, 2000, 1800, 1500, 2000]
    }
  ]
}
```

Los datos en mi vista blade se presentan con un foreach de esta forma:

```
@foreach ($montos as $monto)
 {{ $monto }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear el array como lo hace ahora mismo en tu controlador pero hacerle un `json_encode()` y mandar como una cadena `json` a un `<input class="array" type="hidden" id="data-chart" name="data" value="{{ $data }}">`:

```html
public function tuFuncion()
{
    $data = json_encode([
        'data' => ['JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
        "datasets" => [
            'backgroundColor' => '#007bff',
            'borderColor' => '#007bff',
            'data' => [1000, 2000, 3000, 2500, 2700, 2500, 7000],
            [
                'backgroundColor' => '#ced4da',
                'borderColor' => '#ced4da',
                'data' => [700, 1700, 2700, 2000, 1800, 1500, 2000]
            ],
        ]
    ]);

    return view('view', compact('data'));
}
```

Y en tu archivo JS buscas el `input` al que le asignamos el valor:

```js
var data = JSON.parse($('#data-chart').val());
```

Y empiezas a acceder a los datos, los vas poniendo como los quieres en tu gráfico y listo

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

const MONTOS = {!! json_encode($montos) !!};

var salesChart  = new Chart($salesChart, {
type   : 'bar',
data   : {
  labels  : ['JUN', 'JUL', 'AUG', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DEC'],
  datasets: [
    {
      backgroundColor: '#007bff',
      borderColor    : '#007bff',
      data           : MONTOS
    },
    {
      backgroundColor: '#ced4da',
      borderColor    : '#ced4da',
      data           : MONTOS
    }
  ]
}
</script>
```

Comment: Explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código: ten en cuenta que otros verán tu respuesta y puede que no comprendan lo que hace. _[es.so] no es un repositorio de código_: lee [answer].